# google cloud appengine deploy: exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: flask

I am trying to deploy a toy fastai model on google cloud platform.

Step #1 - "builder": INFO tar_runtime_package took 23 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: gzip_tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpuJcM44.tar -1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO gzip_tar_runtime_package took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO building_python_pkg_layer took 29 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO uploading_all_package_layers took 34 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 258 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 258 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpuJcM44.tar -1
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": gzip_tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder": exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/**main**.py", line 65, in 
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/**main**.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/**main**/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20190527_3_7_3_RC00" failed: exit status 1